# Functions do not export. PowerShell 7.0.2 on Linux

Tags: powershell-core, powershell-7.0

### TL;DR

Running PowerShell 7.0.2 on Linux (Fedora 32), the module loads, but no functions are exported.

### Details

I've written a very basic test module on Linux, which won't export any functions. I've tried it on Windows PowerShell and it does work. What am I missing?

On Windows, it doesn't matter where the .psd1 file is and I would hope the same applies to Linux, but to be sure I have the module inside one of the paths listed in $env:PSModulePath:  /home/john/.local/share/powershell/Modules/testmodule/testmodule.psd1`

I used `New-ModuleManifest` to create the `psd1` file:

```
New-ModuleManifest -Guid ((New-Guid).Guid) -CompanyName "SomeCompany" -Author "John" -Description "Test" -Path ./testmodule.psd1
```

And completed the rest, namely `RootModule`, `CompatiblePSEditions` and `FunctionsToExport`:

```
#
# Module manifest for module 'testmodule'
#
# Generated by: John
#
# Generated on: 08/07/2020
#

@{

# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
# RootModule = 'testmodule.psm1'

# Version number of this module.
ModuleVersion = '0.0.1'

# Supported PSEditions
CompatiblePSEditions = @('Core', 'Desktop')

# ID used to uniquely identify this module
GUID = '372adc51-3efb-4854-9deb-39ea0f9a41eb'

# Author of this module
Author = 'John'

# Company or vendor of this module
CompanyName = 'SomeCompany'

# Copyright statement for this module
Copyright = '(c) John. All rights reserved.'

# Description of the functionality provided by this module
Description = 'Test'

# Minimum version of the PowerShell engine required by this module
# PowerShellVersion = ''

# Name of the PowerShell host required by this module
# PowerShellHostName = ''

# Minimum version of the PowerShell host required by this module
# PowerShellHostVersion = ''

# Minimum version of Microsoft .NET Framework required by this module. This prerequisite is valid for the PowerShell Desktop edition only.
# DotNetFrameworkVersion = ''

# Minimum version of the common language runtime (CLR) required by this module. This prerequisite is valid for the PowerShell Desktop edition only.
# ClrVersion = ''

# Processor architecture (None, X86, Amd64) required by this module
# ProcessorArchitecture = ''

# Modules that must be imported into the global environment prior to importing this module
# RequiredModules = @()

# Assemblies that must be loaded prior to importing this module
# RequiredAssemblies = @()

# Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module.
# ScriptsToProcess = @()

# Type files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
# TypesToProcess = @()

# Format files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
# FormatsToProcess = @()

# Modules to import as nested modules of the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess
# NestedModules = @()

# Functions to export from this module, for best performance, do not use wildcards and do not delete the entry, use an empty array if there are no functions to export.
FunctionsToExport = @('Get-HelloWorld')

# Cmdlets to export from this module, for best performance, do not use wildcards and do not delete the entry, use an empty array if there are no cmdlets to export.
CmdletsToExport = @()

# Variables to export from this module
VariablesToExport = '*'

# Aliases to export from this module, for best performance, do not use wildcards and do not delete the entry, use an empty array if there are no aliases to export.
AliasesToExport = @()

# DSC resources to export from this module
# DscResourcesToExport = @()

# List of all modules packaged with this module
# ModuleList = @()

# List of all files packaged with this module
# FileList = @()

# Private data to pass to the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess. This may also contain a PSData hashtable with additional module metadata used by PowerShell.
PrivateData = @{

    PSData = @{

        # Tags applied to this module. These help with module discovery in online galleries.
        # Tags = @()

        # A URL to the license for this module.
        # LicenseUri = ''

        # A URL to the main website for this project.
        # ProjectUri = ''

        # A URL to an icon representing this module.
        # IconUri = ''

        # ReleaseNotes of this module
        # ReleaseNotes = ''

        # Prerelease string of this module
        # Prerelease = ''

        # Flag to indicate whether the module requires explicit user acceptance for install/update/save
        # RequireLicenseAcceptance = $false

        # External dependent modules of this module
        # ExternalModuleDependencies = @()

    } # End of PSData hashtable

} # End of PrivateData hashtable

# HelpInfo URI of this module
# HelpInfoURI = ''

# Default prefix for commands exported from this module. Override the default prefix using Import-Module -Prefix.
# DefaultCommandPrefix = ''

}
```

I've also created the following, very basic `testmodule.psm1` file:

```
function Get-HelloWord($Name)
{
  Write-Host "Hello '$Name'"
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

When running `Import-Module`, no functions are exported:

```
PS /> Import-Module -FullyQualifiedName "/home/john/.local/share/powershell/Modules/testmodule/testmodule.psd1" -force -verbose
VERBOSE: Loading module from path '/home/john/.local/share/powershell/Modules/testmodule/testmodule.psd1'.
PS />
```

And trying to list the cmdlets with Get-Command, returns nothing:

```
PS /> Get-Command -Module testmodule
PS />
```

Interestingly, I can tab-complete the module name, however, `Get-Module -ListAvailable` does not return any reference to `testmodule`.

Modules such as `Az` installed from PowerShell Gallery work, so I must be doing something wrong. I thought it was the `CompatiblePSEditions`, but adding `core` has made no difference.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be most grateful.

T.I.A

Comment: Looks like you forgot to uncomment `# RootModule = 'testmodule.psm1'` in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing and I learned what I'm about to say from trial and error. I'm not sure it's stated anywhere. Functions to export simply makes a function available in your module. To export it from your module you should also add it to NestedModules. See example below.

**edit**

What I have said above may only be necessary when writing a module with a manifest `*.psd1`. I believe you could also just get rid of the manifest and the functions will appear. There are some short comings with not providing a manifest however.

**testmodule.psd1**

```
#
# Module manifest for module 'testmodule'
#
# Generated by: John
#
# Generated on: 08/07/2020
#

@{

    # Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
    # RootModule = 'testmodule.psm1'

    # Version number of this module.
    ModuleVersion = '0.0.1'

    # Supported PSEditions
    CompatiblePSEditions = @('Core', 'Desktop')

    # ID used to uniquely identify this module
    GUID = '372adc51-3efb-4854-9deb-39ea0f9a41eb'

    # Author of this module
    Author = 'John'

    # Company or vendor of this module
    CompanyName = 'SomeCompany'

    # Copyright statement for this module
    Copyright = '(c) John. All rights reserved.'

    # Description of the functionality provided by this module
    Description = 'Test'

    # Minimum version of the PowerShell engine required by this module
    # PowerShellVersion = ''

    # Name of the PowerShell host required by this module
    # PowerShellHostName = ''

    # Minimum version of the PowerShell host required by this module
    # PowerShellHostVersion = ''

    # Minimum version of Microsoft .NET Framework required by this module. This prerequisite is valid for the PowerShell Desktop edition only.
    # DotNetFrameworkVersion = ''

    # Minimum version of the common language runtime (CLR) required by this module. This prerequisite is valid for the PowerShell Desktop edition only.
    # ClrVersion = ''

    # Processor architecture (None, X86, Amd64) required by this module
    # ProcessorArchitecture = ''

    # Modules that must be imported into the global environment prior to importing this module
    # RequiredModules = @()

    # Assemblies that must be loaded prior to importing this module
    # RequiredAssemblies = @()

    # Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module.
    # ScriptsToProcess = @()

    # Type files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
    # TypesToProcess = @()

    # Format files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
    # FormatsToProcess = @()

    # Modules to import as nested modules of the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess
    NestedModules = @('Get-HelloWorld')

    # Functions to export from this module, for best performance, do not use wildcards and do not delete the entry, use an empty array if there are no functions to export.
    FunctionsToExport = @()

    # Cmdlets to export from this module, for best performance, do not use wildcards and do not delete the entry, use an empty array if there are no cmdlets to export.
    CmdletsToExport = @()

    # Variables to export from this module
    VariablesToExport = '*'

    # Aliases to export from this module, for best performance, do not use wildcards and do not delete the entry, use an empty array if there are no aliases to export.
    AliasesToExport = @()

    # DSC resources to export from this module
    # DscResourcesToExport = @()

    # List of all modules packaged with this module
    # ModuleList = @()

    # List of all files packaged with this module
    # FileList = @()

    # Private data to pass to the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess. This may also contain a PSData hashtable with additional module metadata used by PowerShell.
    PrivateData = @{

        PSData = @{

            # Tags applied to this module. These help with module discovery in online galleries.
            # Tags = @()

            # A URL to the license for this module.
            # LicenseUri = ''

            # A URL to the main website for this project.
            # ProjectUri = ''

            # A URL to an icon representing this module.
            # IconUri = ''

            # ReleaseNotes of this module
            # ReleaseNotes = ''

            # Prerelease string of this module
            # Prerelease = ''

            # Flag to indicate whether the module requires explicit user acceptance for install/update/save
            # RequireLicenseAcceptance = $false

            # External dependent modules of this module
            # ExternalModuleDependencies = @()

        } # End of PSData hashtable

    } # End of PrivateData hashtable

    # HelpInfo URI of this module
    # HelpInfoURI = ''

    # Default prefix for commands exported from this module. Override the default prefix using Import-Module -Prefix.
    # DefaultCommandPrefix = ''

    }
```

```
Import-Module ./testmodule.psm1

Get-Command -Module testmodule                

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Get-HelloWord                                      0.0        testmodule
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go. It's a lot of work to get a whole load of existing PS modules to work on Linux and as you say, I wonder why MS haven't documented it.

Comment: This is not platform specific. I just did a test and I believe your module will export the functions as written, if you get rid of the manifest file. I agree that it can be a pain to export everything, this is why I build all of my manifests dynamically.